# Xcode iphone checkered effect image

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have 1 imageView and 2 pickerView with numbers 1-9 in it.
For example if user select 3 on first picker and 4 on second, I want to show how image in imageView would be cut. 
This select 3 and 4 means 3 columns and 4 rows and I want to paint 2 vertical and 3 horizontal lines on my imageView.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: How to paint this lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

aaaa...in ImageView's drawRect method... split the width and the height according to the numbers in pickers and then do something like: (pseudocode)

```
float widthSplit=imageview.width/widthPiker.value;
float heightSplit=imageview.height/heightPiker.value;

for (int i=0; i<widthPiker.value; i++){
draw line (CGPointMake(0,i*widthSplit) , CGPointMake(imageview.height,i*widthSplit))
}
```

same thing for height

you can set your like width,color & all that by yourself just look at a core graphics drawing tutorial

Comment: I created drawRect method, but it was not called. After that I create 
- (void)drawLine
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blueColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 3.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 50, 50);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
and call it manually, but it is not drawing any lines.

Comment: call it manually? you mean drawRect? cuz that shouldn't work at all..if you need just call [imageView setNeedsDisplay]. That's the only you can trigger draw rect yourself...also...all drawing code must me in drawRect method..(don't make function and then call it in drawRect)